# How can I refresh data without clearing cache? - Problem with volly library

Tags: android, android-volley

there

I'm developing android application which can grab data from web service through GSON and volley. Data can easily fetch from the server for the first time, but when I update data from the server data is not get updated in my application even after restarting the app.

Data may be stored in cache because when I remove that cache data from application data get refresh!

Below is my MainActivity code....

```
            userList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myImgRecyclerView);
            userList.setHasFixedSize(true);
            userList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("CODE", response);
                    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
                    Img[] users = gson.fromJson(response, Img[].class);
                    MyAdapter ma = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, users);
                    userList.setAdapter(ma);
                    ma.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
            queue.add(request);
            queue.start();
```

So please give me some solution for refreshing data without clearing cache data!

Thanking you.

Comment: Does the log show that the correct response is reaching the app?

Comment: By the way where is this code being called?

Comment: Yes @Juan I'm getting proper data from the web but when I update data to web, it is not refreshing in my android application till I clear cache memory!

Comment: Where is this code being called. Do you see the code running when you click to update from the app?

Comment: As far as I see the code posted, I would create the adapter in onCreate() instead of the callback, and implement a replaceDataSource() method to pass in a new dataset (then use that in Volley's callback), but I don't think the problem is there. Can you also add the RV Adapter?